# Calculate 7, 14 and 30 day moving average in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am playing around with bigquery. I have IoT uptime recordings as input:

```
+---------------+-------------+----------+------------+
|   device_id   |  reference  |  uptime  | timestamp  |
+---------------+-------------+----------+------------+
| 1             | 1000-5      |  0.7     | 2019-02-12 |
| 2             | 1000-6      |  0.9     | 2019-02-12 |
| 1             | 1000-5      |  0.8     | 2019-02-11 |
| 2             | 1000-6      |  0.95    | 2019-02-11 |
+---------------+-------------+----------+------------+
```

I want to calculate the 7, 14 and 30 day moving average of the uptime grouped by device. The output should look as follows:

```
+---------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+
|   device_id   |  reference  |  avg_7  | avg_14 | avg_30 |
+---------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+
| 1             | 1000-5      |  0.7    | ..     | ..     |
| 2             | 1000-6      |  0.9    | ..     | ..     |
+---------------+-------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT
    device_id,
    AVG(uptime) OVER (ORDER BY day RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_7d
FROM (
  SELECT device_id, uptime, UNIX_DATE(DATE(timestamp)) as day FROM `uptime_recordings`
)
GROUP BY device_id, uptime, day
```

I have recordings for 1000 distinct devices and 200k readings. The grouping does not work and the query returns 200k records instead of 1000. Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have recordings for 1000 distinct devices and 200k readings. The grouping does not work and the query returns 200k records instead of 1000. Any ideas whats wrong?

Instead of `GROUP BY device_id, uptime, day` do `GROUP BY device_id, day`.

A full working query:

```
WITH data 
AS (
  SELECT title device_id, views uptime, datehour timestamp
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
  WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-09'
  AND wiki='br'
  AND title='Chile'
)

SELECT device_id, day
  , AVG(uptime) OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(day) RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_7d
FROM (
  SELECT device_id, AVG(uptime) uptime, (DATE(timestamp)) as day
  FROM `data`
  GROUP BY device_id, day
)
```

[image]

Edit: As per requested in the comments, not sure what's the goal of summarizing all of the 7d averages:

```
WITH data 
AS (
  SELECT title device_id, views uptime, datehour timestamp
  FROM `fh-bigquery.wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2019` 
  WHERE DATE(datehour) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-09'
  AND wiki='br'
  AND title IN ('Chile', 'Saozneg')
)

SELECT device_id, AVG(avg_7d) avg_avg_7d
FROM (
  SELECT device_id, day
    , AVG(uptime) OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(day) RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg_7d
  FROM (
    SELECT device_id, AVG(uptime) uptime, (DATE(timestamp)) as day
    FROM `data`
    GROUP BY device_id, day
  )
)
GROUP BY device_id
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Felipe :-) How can I group by device_id without grouping by day? Can I still get the 7day avg?

Comment: Just like in the query I pasted?

Comment: I cannot remove the grouping by timestamp because of "SELECT list expression references column timestamp which is neither grouped nor aggregated at". I want the avg_7d not per day and per device_id, but just per device_id.

Comment: Not sure what's the goal of summarizing all of the 7d averages, but check the query I added